# Converting a String to Time(7) Using Azure Data Factory Expressions

Tags: azure-data-factory, sqldatatypes

I have two tables, one is a legacy table I am migrating from that uses strings to denote a date range. For example: `"07:00 AM - 19:00 PM"`.

This is then separated using derived columns into two columns, lets call them "Start" and "End" in my sink table which have a data type `time(7)`.

Is there a argument for `toTimeStamp` or is there another way to achieve converting a string to a date(7) format?

Using string manipulation I can get the string representation of what I need, i.e. "07:00" and "19:00", using something like `substring(MySourceColumn, 12, 5)` in the expression builder but when trying to use `toTimeStamp()` it always resolves into NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toTimestamp()` function in Azure Data Factory to convert a string to a date format. However, since you only need the time component of the date, you can use the `substring()` function to extract the time portion of the string and then concatenate it with a dummy date to create a datetime value.

**Input data:**

```
id,MySourceColumn
1,9:00 AM - 11:30 AM
2,6:00 AM - 11:00 AM
```

- Source transformation is taken with the dataset contains above sample data. Then Derive transformation is taken and expression for `StartTime` and `EndTime` is given as,

```
StartTime =  toTimestamp('1900-01-01 '  +  substring(MySourceColumn, 1, 7) , 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a'),

EndTime =  toTimestamp('1900-01-01 '  +  substring(MySourceColumn, 10,9) , 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a')
```

[image]

The `toTimestamp()` function is used to convert the date and time values in the "MySourceColumn" column to timestamps. The `substring()` function is used to extract the date and time values from the "MySourceColumn" column. The resulting timestamps are stored in the "StartTime" and "EndTime" columns.

- Then sink transformation is taken with the SQL database.

When pipeline is run, only time value will be copied to SQL database.

[image]